# How to approxmate a real number by a sum of two real with integer weights?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, real-numbers, integers, diophantine-approximation

Given three real numbers, $a$, $b$, and $c$, I am wondering how to approximate $c$ by the sum $an+bm$ for integers $n$ and $m$ up to the desired accuracy. More precisely, define $z:\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{R}$,
$$z(n,m):=an+bm+c.$$
Given a positive real $\varepsilon$, find $m$ and $n$ such that $|z(m,n)|\le \varepsilon$.

I failed to google any sufficient claim when it is possible. Is it possible for an arbitrary $\varepsilon$, and how to solve it? If it changes, we can consider $a$, $b$, and $c$ as rationals.

**Example**
Find integers $m$ and $n$ such that
$$\left|\frac{2}{3}n + \frac{7}{9}m + \frac{3}{4} \right|\le 0.01.$$

Comment: If $a/b$ is rational, say $a/b=p/q$ for some integers $p,q$, then this won't in general be possible, as then $an+bm$ is of the form $\frac{a}{p}N$ for some integer $N$ (specifically, $N=pn+qm$); so all expressible numbers are at least a distance $a/p$ from each other. But if $a/b$ is irrational, you can approximate $-c$ as closely as you like by choosing large enough $n,m$.

Comment: @TonyK Thanks, I see. However, it's really not intuitive to me. I mean, if $a/b$ is rational, then there exists $a^*$ arbitrary close to $a$ such that $a^*/b$ is irrational, right? My intuition was that this "arbitrary close" yields arbitrary accurate approximation. But it seems I was wrong.

Comment: It takes a while to develop an intuition for such things! It comes from studying examples such as this.

Comment: What TonyK said. In your example case, the set of numbers of the form $\dfrac23n+\dfrac79m$ is the same set as $\dfrac19\ell$. That is a discrete set, and the closest it gets to $-3/4$ is at $-7/9$. OTOH if $a/b$ is irrational, then the subgroup of numbers of the form $na+mb$ is dense, which is exactly your goal.